# How to find the byte offset of an object in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, object, g++, offset

Let's say I create 5 objects, all from the same class.  Would the byte offset of the first object be 0?  How would I find out the byte offset of the other objects?

Comment: Offset from what?  Are these objects member variables of a class?  Are they in an array?

Comment: Offset relative to what?

Answer (score 0):

"Byte offset" from *what*?  Are you creating an *array* of 5 such objects?  In that case, sure, the byte offset of the first one (from the start of the array) is 0; as for other objects,

```
static_cast<char*>(&thearray[i]) - static_cast<char*>(&thearray[0])
```

is the byte offset of the `i`th one.

Comment: You'd either have to reinterpret_cast to char* or add another static_cast through void*.  That said, `i * sizeof thearray[0]` should work just as well since array elements must occupy contiguous storage.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you mean by `offset`, you can always examine the address of the objects yourself:

```
printf("%p %p", (void *) &thingOne, (void *) &thingTwo);
```